# Symfony2 project css not doing its thing

Tags: symfony, assetic

I have installed and dumped assetic properly but css is somehow not loading. In config file i have bundles on which assetic operates. But, on page get plain html w/o style,.
When i open the debugger in the network/stylesheet tab everything looks fine, css files are loaded properly except one typekit file with 403 error.

Is it possible that css is not working because of single css file with 403 error while being loaded?

I tried to switch browsers but same thing happens.

EDIT:
The problem is with the response type that got changed when i messed with cache. For css i get text/html. How do i fix that?

Answer (score 0):

You likely have your firewall setting in your security.yml set to be too restrictive.

You will want to have a firewall for your assets something like:

```
#app/config/security.yml
#...
firewalls:
    assets:
        pattern: ^/(css|js|img)/
        security: false
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to be a problem.

Comment: If you access the css url directly do you you see all of your styles there? Also can you add the html you are using to load the stylesheet

Comment: When i click on the stylesheet in page source i can see my styles..i use 
{% block stylesheet %}{% endblock %} in twig to load them across application. This problem appeared suddenly so i guess it has nothing to do with markup.